# Cannot connect SensorTag cc2650 to IBM watson IoT platform using their android app

Tags: mqtt, sensors

I have SensorTag cc2650 from Texas Instruments with their android app installed in my Phone. I am getting an exception while connecting IBM Watson IoT. It worked fine with quick-start service but gives me exception when I connect it to my registered service with Platform.

**Working fine with quick-start:**

[image]

credentials that I have added in mobile App are:

[image]

**The exception that I receives:**

[image]

On IBM Watson IoT platform I have created device here is that:

[image]

And this is screen-shot of IBM IoT Platform Dashboard:

[image]

What is the issue? I read [this](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/connect-a-cc2650-sensortag-to-the-iot-foundations-quickstart/) recipe. There was procedure with screenshots for iOS but for android it was written that author will update android screen shots soon. but he hasn't updated yet.

I also set TLS optional security as mentioned in [this](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/368104/unable-to-connect-ti-sensor-tag-to-iotf-registered/) post put issue still persists.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it. Issue was resolved by following these steps:

1. I create a new device with type `ti-sensortag2` from IBM watson IoT dashboard. instead of with type`iotsample-ti-cc2650`
2. passed `d:5j6cf4:ti-sensortag2:546c0e5301e1` in device id.
3. Last thing that I rectified was to mention my organization id in broker id which I passed in app . So this came out to be my new broker id `tcp://5j6cf4.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com`

The new credentials for Cloud Setup in SensorTag app are shown in this screen-shot:

[image]

after that I clicked **push to cloud** toggle button and it started sending data to my iot service:

[image]

and I was able to receive data in recent events like this:

[image]